# Глобальный перехват Exception в JavaEE при ajax запросе

Tags: java, ajax, исключения

Подскажите пожалуйста. Как сделать глобальный перехват ошибок возникающих на стороне сервера при `ajax` запросе на сервлет. Под глобальным я имею в виду один механизм - будь то класс или функция которая перехватывает `Exception`-ы возникающие в `.class` файлах перед ответом. 
Сейчас это работает таким образом что мне в ответ приходит вся информация об ошибке - это статус (код - 500, 400 и т.д.), сообщение (пример - `java.lang.NumberFormatException: null`) и так называемый `StackTrace` (детали ошибки - указание классов и т.д.). Мне же нужно в ответ только статус и сообщение и вывести это юзеру. 
Как это сделать?

Использую **Servlet API**

Comment: Добавьте подробностей в вопрос. JavaEE - это довольно широкое понятие. Что именно вы используете: Spring, JAX-RS, чистый Servlet API?

Comment: @Nofate Servlet API

Answer (score 1):

в web.xml пропиши

```xml
 <web-app ...>
    <error-page>
        <location>/errorPage</location>
    </error-page>
 </web-app>
```

или

```xml
 <web-app ...>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/errorPage</location>
    </error-page>
 </web-app>
```

Comment: это будет работать для `ajax` запросов?

Comment: Будет работать для всех запросов к приложению

Comment: AJAX - слово, которое для сервера ничего не значит. Отличия лишь на стороне клиента: в том, что это ассинхронные запросы.